# ggplot2 - barplot moving order

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

By default `ggplot2` keeps the orders of variables *constant* in a plot, for example here: `a` will stay at the bottom, `b` in the middle, and `c` at the top.

[image]

What I would like to produce a graph where the order changes depending on the changing proportions (`%`).

So, **time** is on the `x-axis` and **proportion** (`%`) on the `y-axis`, like in a regular barplot.

You can visualise the table like this :

```
    code  color   `1`   `2`   `3`
1      a    red   0.2   0.8   0.2
2      b   blue   0.8   0.0   0.2
3      c yellow   0.0   0.2   0.6
```

**What I would like is this**:

[image]

The plot is ordered now according to the proportion. This enables to visualise more easily the hierarchy between the states over time. First `blue` (b) is more prominent, then `red` (a) and finally `yellow` (c). The order between the states in the plot can change.

However, I am not quite sure how to do it.

I tried using `order`: `order(n)` like :

```
td %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(ord = order(n, decreasing = T))
```

and to explicitly provide the position to `ggplot`

but it doesn't seem to work.

```
t %>% 
  count(time, code) %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(n = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, n, fill = code)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'blue', 'yellow')) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = factor(td$ord)) # positions #
```

**data**

```
t = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "factor"), code = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "code", "time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply order your `data.frame` according to column `n`, before calling `ggplot()`:

```
t %>% 
  count(time, code) %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(n = n / sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% # only need to add this line
  ggplot(aes(time, n, fill = code)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'blue', 'yellow'))
```

[image]